# Dust and radiation equation of state

Tags: condensed-matter, photons, astrophysics, relativity, matter

Does anyone know what is the equation of state,
$$
P=w\rho \hspace{5mm} w\in \mathbb{R}
$$
for 'dust' and radiation (photon gas)? *i.e.*, I want the number $w$ for both cases.

Can $w$ be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $w$ is simply defined as $w$ = p/$\rho$ for a perfect fluid equation of state. It is easy in cosmology to use $w$ as a parameter (or function) that defines the different equations of state

For cold matter, i.e. dust, $w$ = 0. This basically says that dust does not produce any pressure.

For radiation $w$ = 1/3. This comes from the pressure exerted by radiation.

For dark energy $w$ = -1. This is the equation of state for the fluid which would be equivalent to the dark energy. $w$ = -1 is equivalent to a free scalar field, and it is used to model a constant dark energy density.

See the Wikipedia article, it's fairly straightforward and explained there. It's at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)

Comment: Great answer, but just a note for the audience: in general $w$ will be temperature (and environment) dependent for baryons.  The $w=0$ for dust is an approximation (that is very accurate for cosmological purposes).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DilithiumMatrix. And the question of when it would have been important or of some significance in the evolution to account for a nonzero $w$, and nonzero pressure, would be temperature and I am guessing also density dependent, and of course what the particles were. If this is correct, any idea of until how long after the Big Bang it made any difference? I don't think I've seen a treatment of it even in early times, but I might have ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Dust has $w=0$, radiation has $w=1/3$.

In normal cases, $w>0$, but if you consider a universe with a cosmological constant, it acts as though $w=-1$.